# How to setup Sony A58 for clear movie recording?

Tags: video-quality, video-recording, dslr, sony

I have a Sony A58 camera and 18-55mm lens. I did some recordings with AF (Auto-Focus). The frames are a bit blurry. They are actually clear, but it seems to me like the camera is taking two shots and then overlaying these to images to form a frame.

When playing the video this comes off as the video is blurred but when I pause the video, you can clearly see the two images in one frame.

I tried different different shutter speeds with MF with no change in the output.

[image: Frame blur]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to change the video file format in the Menu:

- From AVCHD to MP4.